# Array in <p> element, each to newline?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, newline

I have managed to insert an array into an p element using

```
document.getElementById("trackdetails").innerHTML = albumarray;
```

Is there anyway to make it so each array element is on a newline? Thank you

Comment: Look into [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to perform an action for every element in array

Comment: albumarray.join('<br/>)

Comment: Do you want each index in its own paragraph tag? What is the expected output??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple join on the array will do it.
If you're listing items, consider whether an unordered list <ul> would be more appropriate. For some background, the Array.prototype.join() function joins all the elements in the array into a string, and the supplied argument gets added in between them. The same thing is also useful for turning an array into a comma-separated list, for example.

```js
var array = ["Stuff", "Foo", "Bar"];
document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = array.join('<br />');
```

```html
<p id="target"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join and pass a `<br />` tag:

```
document.getElementById("trackdetails").innerHTML = albumarray.join("<br />");
```